# extracting the top 25 percentile of a sub list in a large data file

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dask, bigdata

I have a large csv file with three columns: `AID, VID, Rel`.

The file is 21 GB.

1. I would like to sort it such that AID is sorted followed by Rel. Result should look like this:

   ```
   AID    VID   Rel
   A      3     0.9
   A      4     0.88
   A      5     0.87
   A      1     0.7
   A      2     0.5
   A      6     0.4
   A      7     0.35
   A      8     0.3
   B      3     0.9
   B      1     0.8
   B      2     0.7
   B      4     0.6
   ```
2. After I sort, I need to extract each AID "block" at a time, and extract the rows in it's top 25th percentile.

I am new to dealing with large data, and not sure how to do that.

I have tried using Python pandas, but it kept crashing. I also tried using Python's dask, but it doesn't sort.

I have access to an HPC cluster if that helps.

Comment: Spin up a Amazon Redshift cluster and it can deal with Tera bytes of data easily and will cost next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Standard pandas syntax does appear to solve this for you:

`import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(...)
out = df.groupby('AID').apply(
    lambda f: f[f.Rel > f.Rel.quantile(0.75)].sort_values(
        'Rel', ascending=False), meta=df)`

`out` is now a dask dataframe, which presumably also does not fit in memory, so what you do with it next is up to you (extract some subset, do calculations, aggregate...).

Since this involves *shuffling* the data, you could still run out of memory, depending on the number of groups you have, and the size/chunks you use for loading the CSVs.